# Error on webm video captured *updated

Tags: javascript, html, getusermedia

***Updated***
The record starts when the user accepts the allow of webcam, and stops when It presses play ( buttton that it was supposed to trigger the record)

When I request user media,and the user accepts it starts recording however when I reproduce it later , It doesn't reproduce properly and the webm doesn't match the beggining of start recording and the end of  recording.

For example I talk to the camera 20seconds, and It returns only 15 14 seconds, and the last seconds are blurry , the sounds and video stops.

I've change some deprecated methods like Navigator.getUserMedia() to navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia() , however still not find why it's happening.

Can anyone help me?

```
function listUserMedia(){

    if (!navigator.mediaDevices || !navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices) {
        console.log("enumerateDevices() not supported.");
        return;
    }

    var media = navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();

    media.then(function(devices) {

        var useVideo=null;
        var useAudio=null;
        devices.forEach(function(device) {

            //console.log(device.kind + ": " + device.label + " id = " + device.deviceId);

            if(device.kind=="audioinput"){
                useAudio="true";

            }

            if(device.kind=="videoinput"){
                useVideo="true";

            }

        });

        if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
            sessionStorage.setItem('useAudio', useAudio);
            sessionStorage.setItem('useVideo', useVideo);
        } else {
            console.log("Unable to set SessionStorage");
        }

    });

    media.catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message);
    });

    if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {

        return {"audio":sessionStorage.getItem('useAudio'),"video":sessionStorage.getItem('useVideo')};
    } else {
        console.log("Unable to get SessionStorage");
    }

    return null;
}


navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;

function requestMedia(string){
    if(typeof MediaRecorder === 'undefined' || !navigator.getUserMedia){

        alert('MediaRecorder/getUserMedia no supported on your browser, kindly use Firefox 36+');
    }else{

        initiateMedia(listUserMedia());
        navigator.getUserMedia(constraint, startRecording, errorCallback);

        var media = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraint);

        media.then(function(mediaStream){
            stream=mediaStream;
            var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
            if(mediaType!=null){

                if(mediaType=="video/webm"){
                    mediactrl.src = url ? url.createObjectURL(stream) : stream;
                    mediactrl.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {

                        mediactrl.play();
                    };
                }else{   if (options.noFallback === undefined || options.noFallback === false) {

                    // Fallback to flash
                    var source, el, cam;

                    source = '<!--[if IE]>'+
                    '<object id="XwebcamXobjectX" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="' + options.width + '" height="' + options.height + '">'+
                    '<param name="movie" value="' + options.swffile + '" />'+
                    '<![endif]-->'+
                    '<!--[if !IE]>-->'+
                    '<object id="XwebcamXobjectX" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="' + options.swffile + '" width="' + options.width + '" height="' + options.height + '">'+
                    '<!--<![endif]-->'+
                    '<param name="FlashVars" value="mode=' + options.mode + '&amp;quality=' + options.quality + '" />'+
                    '<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />'+
                    '</object>';
                    el = document.getElementById(options.el);
                    el.innerHTML = source;


                    (function register(run) {

                        cam = document.getElementById('XwebcamXobjectX');

                        if (cam.capture !== undefined) {

                            // Simple callback methods are not allowed 
                            options.capture = function (x) {
                                try {
                                    return cam.capture(x);
                                } catch (e) {}
                            };
                            options.save = function (x) {
                                try {
                                    return cam.save(x);
                                } catch (e) {

                                }
                            };
                            options.setCamera = function (x) {
                                try {
                                    return cam.setCamera(x);
                                } catch (e) {}
                            };
                            options.getCameraList = function () {
                                try {
                                    return cam.getCameraList();
                                } catch (e) {}
                            };

                            // options.onLoad();
                            options.context = 'flash';
                            options.onLoad = successCallback;

                        } else if (run === 0) {
                            // options.debug("error", "Flash movie not yet registered!");
                            errorCallback();
                        } else {
                            // Flash interface not ready yet 
                            window.setTimeout(register, 1000 * (4 - run), run - 1);
                        }
                    }(3));

                }

                    mediactrl.src = url ? url.createObjectURL(stream) : stream;
                    mediactrl.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {

                        mediactrl.play();
                    }
                }
                $("#requestmedia").addClass("btndisabled");
                $("#videocontrol").removeClass("btndisabled").prop("disabled",false);
                $("#mediaerror").html(string).css({"display":"block","color":"#003666"});
            }

        });

        media.catch(function(err){
            errorCallback(err);
        });
    }

}



function startRecording(stream){


    if (typeof MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported == 'function'){
        if (MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported('video/webm;codecs=vp9')) {
                var options = {mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=vp9'};
        } else if (MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported('video/webm;codecs=vp8')) {
                var options = {mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=vp8'};
        }

        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);

    }else{
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream); //Default codec for browser
    }

    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
    mediaRecorder.start(10);


    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e){
        chunks.push(e.data);
    };

    mediaRecorder.onerror = function(e){
        console.log("Error: "+e)    
    };

    mediaRecorder.onstop = function(){
        var blob = new Blob(chunks, {type: mediaType});
        chunks = [];
        var mediaURL = (window.webkitURL || window.URL).createObjectURL(blob);
        sendFileToServer(blob);
        //console.log(mediaURL);
    };



}

function errorCallback(error){
  console.log('navigator.getUserMedia error: ', error);
}

function releaseDevice(){

    if(stream && stream.stop){
        //stream.stop();

        if(mediaType=="video/webm"){
        stream.getVideoTracks()[0].stop();  
        stream.getAudioTracks()[0].stop();
        }else{
        stream.getAudioTracks()[0].stop();
        }


    }

    stream=null;
}
```